# Swift - draggable UIView with animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I am trying to implement a draggable UIView that appears after the user clicks on a `cell` in my `CollectionView`. The view should then be dismissable by dragging down. Right now I am achieving this in a rather ugly way like this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // if indexPath.item is less than data count, return a "Content" cell
    if indexPath.item < wishListTitlesArray.count {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell

        cell.testLabel.text = wishListTitlesArray[indexPath.item]

        cell.buttonView.setImage(wishListImagesArray[indexPath.item], for: .normal)

        cell.customWishlistTapCallback = {

            // let wishlistView appear

            // track selected index
            self.currentWishListIDX = indexPath.item
            // update label in wishList view
            self.wishlistLabel.text = self.wishListTitlesArray[indexPath.item]
            // update image in wishList view
            self.wishlistImage.image = self.wishListImagesArray[indexPath.item]
            // update the data for in wishList table view
            self.theTableView.wishList = self.userWishListData[indexPath.item]
            // reload wishList table
            self.theTableView.tableView.reloadData()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.wishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            })
            // let welcomeText disappear
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.welcomeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -270, y: 0)
            })
        }
        return cell
    }
```

To dismiss the view I added a `gestureRegocnizer`:

```
@objc func dismissView(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    hideView()
}

@objc func hideView(){
    //animate welcomeLabel
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

        // show welcomeText
        self.welcomeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        // hide wishlistView
        self.wishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1000)
    })

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        // hide wishlistView
        self.wishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1000)
    })
}
```

The problem with that solution is that it is not very smooth because the view is not really draggable like you would expect it from a lot of other views inside apps nowadays. The view disappears as soon as the user just slightly drags down and he is not able to hold it and drag it up again. I hope you understand what I mean.

N26 is using the exact transition that I would like to have inside my app so here is a link for a better understanding:

[N26 App transition](https://streamable.com/zi8u0)

Comment: I would usually use a Cocoapod for something like this. Does the sample animation on this one look like what you want? https://github.com/shingt/DraggableModalTransition

Comment: looks good, I will give it a try thanks :)